# Why is there [google-glass] and [google-gdk]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Why are there [google-glass](/questions/tagged/google-glass) and [google-gdk](/questions/tagged/google-gdk) on the main site? Shouldn't one be a synonym of the other?

I know SE is getting a cut, but they should be the same.

Comment: Because it is potentially possible to ask a question about one but not the other :)

Comment: @Mansfield example?

Comment: There are tags for both Iphone and Iphone-sdk, for example. Not quite what you're looking for, but a similar situation there.

Comment: What about [tag:google-mirror-api]? That doesn't require running code on the Glass, so it seems like [tag:google-glass] could apply while [tag:google-gdk] might not.

Comment: @thegrinner true - but google-glass might be redundant in both cases.

Comment: You're right about it being redundant, but they aren't really synonyms. Another possible case: what if you need to fix how your website works with Glass? Looking at the [support page](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3231625?hl=en), it seems there are unique limitations for the platform (no flash, no typing, etc).

Answer (score 6):

[google-glass](/questions/tagged/google-glass) is an inclusive tag, indicating a question about the Google Glass product. One might ask a hardware question as well as a software question with this tag.
[google-gdk](/questions/tagged/google-gdk) and [google-mirror-api](/questions/tagged/google-mirror-api) refer to two different app development techniques for software that interacts with the Google Glass product. Questions wiht [google-glass](/questions/tagged/google-glass) may also be just about how to use the Google Glass product or with web considerations (see [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3231625?hl=en)):

> - Glass doesn't currently support signing in to websites or the use of other forms. You'll probably need to find a device capable of typing for that.
> - While some YouTube videos will play normally, many others (including those requiring Flash) won't.

The two tags are definitely different.

Comment: I thought I would try to build off what someone else did ... I did not mean to offend you in any way, pardon me if I did. I thought it would be clearer to other folk who look at the original question if there weren't competing answers and yours contained much good information.